# Sql query to sum and group by id

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table *abc* where there can be one or more rows against one **UserId**. 
*abc* table has column **value**. I want the results to be the summation of the **value** of each **UserId**.

Example: userId 1 -> 41, userId 2 -> 98

What I have now:

```
SELECT (UserPersonalDetailsId),
        SUM(anyValue) AS anyValueName
    FROM [dbo].Experience
    GROUP BY UserPersonalDetailsId
```

Result: It's returning the summation of every row individually. So I have like:

UserId 1 -> 25, UserId 1 -> 10, UserId 2 -> 5 etc.

What should I change or add to complete the query?

PS. I know it's a very common/easy solution but can't seem to find any. :(

Comment: Watch the video and solve the exercise for reference- [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/sql-grouping-select-results-with-group-by/5520132919132160)

Answer (score 7):

You should group by `UserId` column not by `UserPersonalDetailsId`.

Try this:

```
SELECT UserId, SUM(anyValue) AS anyValueName
    FROM [dbo].Experience
    GROUP BY UserId
```

Comment: he he he, that was a typing mistake. But I found the problem, I had some other column grouping other than userId, removing the other columns fixed the problem. Thanks though!

Comment: should i delete the question? It's not gonna help anybody.

Comment: Yes, I think so

Comment: ha ha, cannot delete it as others have put their efforts!

Answer (score 2):

You can try partition by as well. Like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT UserId, SUM(anyValue) OVER (PARTITION BY UserId) AS anyValueName
FROM [dbo].Experience
```